# Properly Format Data in CSV for Easy Import with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Currently I am storing my data in the following manner in a csv file:

```
a,b,c
1 1 1 1,22 22 22,333 333 333
10 10 10, 20 20 20, 30 30 30
```

However, this turns out to be a major pain in Pandas or in R's dataframe because by default, each language treats the values as strings. I therefore have to manually fix-up each string to be an array (split on spaces, converts strings to floats/ints etc). Is there a more efficient way to store the data so I can read the data out as arrays of floats immediately?

Comment: do your lists have different or the same length?

Comment: Yes they are the same length.

Comment: in this case i would try to convert your DFs into Panels (3D objects) and then store them as PyTables (HDF5 storage). You could consider your columns as __Data Frames__ with flatten data (no lists)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
df[columns] = df[columns].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
# astype
df[columns] = df[columns].astype('float32')
```